# laravel execute code after return

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to execude some code after I return View::make('view');
Is that possible in laravel? I know I can put my code Into my view but its kind of bad practice, here is my code :

```html
if (!$conversation == null) {
   // here I update last_viewed time
      $conversation_memb=$conversation->members()->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();
      $conversation_memb->last_viewed = time();
      $conversation_memb->save();
      
            // here I return View with some data
   return View::make('messages.conversation')->with('conversation',$conversation)->with('messages',$conversation->messages()->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->take(10)->get()->reverse());
   
  }
```

So I'd like to update time of last_view only after I load the view, so the messages will be shown like "Unread"

Comment: Once you return from a function, that function is done. Note that any php code, whether in the controller or in the view, will be executed before the response is sent to the client. If you need it done in the browser, you'll need to use Javascript. You could probably use an ajax request to update the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking about the problem the wrong way. You don't need to update the data after the view has been displayed; instead of this, simply let the view know about what is going on.

Presumably right now the view knows if a message is unread or not by comparing some timestamp with a `last_viewed` value that it gets by reaching directly into `$conversation`. Don't do that. Save the previous `last_viewed` value before you update the database into a variable, pass that variable into the view and have the view compare with that.

Answer (score 4):

Using Laravel, you can run such tasks after sending the response to the user. It works by keeping the PHP process alive to run the tasks after closing the connection with the browser. You can do that using:

`Job::dispatchAfterResponse()` using Laravel v6.14.0 or higher.